# {"message":"User is unauthorized"} shows in nodejs project

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, pm2, nvm

I'm facing an issue with my nodejs project which is deployed on AWS ubuntu machine.
My website on the aws machine is showing message

[image: {"message":"User is unauthorized"}]

I'm using pm2 manager for running the process.
I faced this issue when I tried to upgrade my nvm from 8.0.0 and currently I'm using 10.23.2

Please let me know if you need further details as I'm new to this environment.

pm2 log is shown as below:

```
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/ente-gramam-api-error-1.log last 15 lines:
1|ente-gra | (node:20721) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose                                                                                                              >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using                                                                                                              `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/co                                                                                                             nnections.html#use-mongo-client

/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/ente-gamam-admin-error-0.log last 15 lines:
0|ente-gam | Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
0|ente-gam | designed for a production environment, as it will leak
0|ente-gam | memory, and will not scale past a single process.
0|ente-gam | Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
0|ente-gam | designed for a production environment, as it will leak
0|ente-gam | memory, and will not scale past a single process.
0|ente-gam | Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
0|ente-gam | designed for a production environment, as it will leak
0|ente-gam | memory, and will not scale past a single process.
0|ente-gam | Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
0|ente-gam | designed for a production environment, as it will leak
0|ente-gam | memory, and will not scale past a single process.
0|ente-gam | Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
0|ente-gam | designed for a production environment, as it will leak
0|ente-gam | memory, and will not scale past a single process.

/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/ente-gamam-admin-out-0.log last 15 lines:
0|ente-gam | Demo application started on port 3002
0|ente-gam | Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
```

Comment: did it work correctly on your local? also please share the url in the above picture.

Comment: I didn't test that in my local yet. Now I tested that and it's showing same error in my local also.